# Two installations of Qt on OSX?

Tags: homebrew

My setup (OSX 10.13.6) appears to have two installations of Qt5: one in `/Library/Frameworks` (`/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework`, `/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework`, etc.), but I also have one installed by `brew` at `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.0`. Is it a good idea to have Qt at two locations? Is it a good idea to remove the one at `/Library/Frameworks` and keep the one `brew` installed?

Answer (score 1):

Often had two versions of a particular app installed (usually in the standard apps location).

Did this with Excel - never had an issue. Also with Qt at one time.

I just made sure the newest one was the most recent install for any libraries necessary.

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade the one in `/L/F`? I'm not even sure if it's Qt5.

Comment: @JohnM. have you tried the System Prefs upgrade? select just that app...

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good idea to remove the one at /Library/Frameworks and keep the one brew installed?

No it isn't a good idea because some previously installed applications (and not standard MacOS ones) are using this library. And these applications won't be compatible with the `brew` version which is *usually* more recent and more secure than this older one, but with different interface (ex.: `f(x,y) → f(x,y,z)`) and behaviour.

On the other hand, the one installed by `brew` will be used to compile and  run any application installed with `brew`.

It is a very good protection that `brew` chosed on purpose not to overwrite the system versions of important libraries. This is a sign of a well conceived package manager, a professionnal tool.

Comment: /LF is not Apple's system library all those are in /System/Library - this one was probably installed by installing Qt directly from a download from QT (or a badly packaged app - well nowadays - for OSX 10.0 this would have been correct)